# SoapUI JDBC connection with Apache Cassandra

Tags: java, jdbc, cassandra, soapui

Does anyone know how to connect to cassandra using JDBC connection string in SoapUI.

I have tried from my side, but not able to connect. Based on the research I came to know that `org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver` doesn't support.

I am using below information.

- Driver: `org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver`
- Connection String: `jdbc:cassandra://localhost:8080/test3`

Comment: What kind of errors or problems do you get?

Comment: I am not getting any response..Normally when I connect to SQL I get message saying Connected Successfully, but not for cassandra

Comment: FYI. I have am using cassandra-jdbc-1.2.5.jar

Comment: 8080 doesn't look like a correct port

Comment: Hi I have even tried default port 9160, but still not been able to connect

Comment: Have you looked at https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-jdbc/ and tried `jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9170/Keyspace1`as the connection string? As for no response, did you check soapUIs error log?

Comment: Hi Abhishek, Yes indeed I have referred to your suggested link, however not able to connect. FYI. the information that I have given above is just for reference as I can't reveal IP address..

Comment: I do not see any messages on SoapUI error logs

Answer (score 3):

These days Thrift is dead in terms of a Cassandra interface, and you need to be using the native CQL protocol to be doing anything useful. Fortunately there is a [JDBC wrapper](https://github.com/adejanovski/cassandra-jdbc-wrapper) available if that's your only integration option, and the native driver's concepts will map a lot better to JDBC than the old Thrift protocol.

> JDBC driver class : com.github.adejanovski.cassandra.jdbc.CassandraDriver
>
> JDBC URL : jdbc:cassandra://host1--host2--host3:9042/keyspace

Where 9042 is the default native transport port, configurable via [cassandra.yaml](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml.html).

There does also appear to be an [updated version](https://github.com/jprante/cassandra-jdbc) of the Thrift-based JDBC driver for use with Cassandra 3.x, but it is no longer supported by Apache or the Cassandra developers.

---

As the other answers here have been sharing fixed lists of (sometimes spurious) dependencies I thought I'd better mention proper dependency management, as a lot of things won't work if the different jar versions don't all match up (in particular, 2.x to 3.x is a breaking change for both Cassandra itself and cassandra-driver-core).

The wrapper project mentioned above contains a pom.xml that specifies all the dependencies and is published to [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/). You should be able to use any number of dependency-management tools -- including maven, ivy or grape -- to resolve and download all the jars you will need for a particular driver version.

Alternatively, it appears the developer provides a single jar containing all the necessary dependencies, but this will be tied to a specific driver version.

Answer (score 0):

This was fun, I have never worked with Cassandra before so it took me sometime to figure this one out and I think i have.

To use Cassandra you need multiple jar files, below is a screenshot of the ones i used.
[image]

I used the cassandra-cli to find out the correct port number, in my case it was `9160`.

The correct connection string is `jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9160/soapuikeyspace` and the correct driver is `org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver`.
When i tried to access Cassandra from teh JDBC step i was able to succesfully connect to Cassandra but when i tried to run a select query i got

> Error getting response

and the following error trace in the soapUI logs

```
Sat Apr 05 17:33:09 ADT 2014:ERROR:java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException
   java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraResultSet$CResultSetMetaData.getTableName(CassandraResultSet.java:1307)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.xml.XmlUtils.addResultSetXmlPart(XmlUtils.java:1712)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.xml.XmlUtils.createJdbcXmlResult(XmlUtils.java:1651)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.JdbcResponse.<init>(JdbcResponse.java:38)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.JdbcSubmit.createResponse(JdbcSubmit.java:334)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.JdbcSubmit.runQuery(JdbcSubmit.java:199)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.JdbcSubmit.run(JdbcSubmit.java:161)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

So that approach was a bust.

It wasn't a complete failure because I was able to access Cassandra and run queries against it. I used the below code to do that.

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.*;

com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils.registerJdbcDriver("org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver");
def con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9160/soapuikeyspace"); //keyspace has to be in lowercase

 def stmt = con.createStatement();

//add data
def qry = "insert into users (user_id, lname, fname) values (1747,'Abhishek','Asthana');"
def rs = stmt.executeUpdate(qry)
```

The most important thing to remember when using this code is to write the keyspace name in lowercase.

For anyone interested, i wrote [a blog about all this](http://abhishekasthana.com/accessing-cassendra-soapui/).

Comment: thank you all for your help. I am now able to connect cassandra via SoapUI.

Comment: using the method i described or through some other way?

Comment: Hi Abhishek, Thank you specially to you. I used your information and script. Appreciate your help

Comment: If this worked for you, could please accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with a creation of Cassandra cluster and using it to connect to the cassandra as following:

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;

def rs;

//query
def qry = "select id soapuikeyspace.users where id='aaa';"

//create cluster for cassandra
Cluster cluster = new Cluster.Builder().addContactPoint("localhost").withCredentials("cassandra", "cassandra").withPort(9042).build();

//get seesionm from cassandra claster
session = cluster.connect();

//get result set
rs = session.execute(qry);
```

Required jar's:

- cassandra-all-2.0.6.jar
- cassandra-driver-core-2.0.1.jar
- netty-3.9.0.Final.jar
- metrics-core-3.0.2.jar

Answer (score 0):

I successfully connected to Cassandra 3.x with a SoapUI version 5.3.0 by cql connection.

Here are my steps:

1. copy these jars into bin/ext:

   > dse-java-driver-core-1.4.0
   >
   > dse-java-driver-mapping-1.4.0
   >
   > metrics-core-3.0.2
   >
   > netty-all-4.1.6.Final
2. update guava jar from lib:

   > guava-18.0
3. launch soapui and create groovy script:

```html
    import com.datastax.driver.core.*;

    Cluster cluster = null;

    cluster = new Cluster.Builder().addContactPoints("127.0.0.1").withPort(9042).build();
    
    Session session = cluster.connect();                         

    PreparedStatement statement = session.prepare("select * from keyspace.exemple_table");

    ResultSet rs = session.execute(statement.bind());

    Row row = rs.one();
```