# Cassandra Connection with Groovy Script In SoapUI

Tags: groovy, cassandra, soapui, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

thanks for the time. I am trying to access a remote Cassandra DB in order to complete my assertions. I see that the Server is running:
Cassandra V 3.0.8.1293
Driver Type: Cassandra CQL
Datastax Java Driver for Apache Cassandra - Core [3.0.5]

So, I am trying with the following simple code to access the DB

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.*

Cluster cluster = null;
try {
cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("x.x.x.x").withCredentials("xxxxxxx", "xxxxxx").withPort(9042).build()

Session session = cluster.connect();                         

ResultSet rs = session.execute("select * from TABLE");   
Row row = rs.one();
} finally {
if (cluster != null) cluster.close();  
}
```

when I use the cassandra-driver-core-2.0.1.jar I am getting the error :

> ERROR:com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /x.x.x.x(null))

Read the documentation and a lot of posts here and on other blogs and I saw that there may be an incompatibility with the driver version so I tried to upgrade the driver to many versions (cassandra-driver-core-2.5,cassandra-driver-core-3,cassandra-driver-core-3.2), but on that I am getting the following:

> ERROR:java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Have also tried to connect using JDBC, but to no avail, using the configuration proposed at this thread
[SoapUI JDBC connection with Apache Cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22659506/soapui-jdbc-connection-with-apache-cassandra)

Actually I am running out of ideas. Can anyone propose or point to some direction on how to actually achieve this, either by pointing me to some tutorial or any idea.
Thank you very much

Comment: Have tried the process described above with a clean installation of SOAPUI 5.3.0 and with the jars of cassandra-driver-core-3.0.5.jar, cassandra-driver-extras-3.0.5.jar, cassandra-driver-mapping-3.0.5.jar on the lib folder

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't enable remote access to cassandra.

Try enabling remote access using below configuration -

File Path `/etc/cassandra/default.conf/cassandra.yaml`

```
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0

broadcast_rpc_address: <serverIPAddress>
```

After that, restart cassandra service.

Comment: That is not the case unfortunately, since I can connect using InteliJ, with the exact same code. The problem seems to be with SOAP UI